# hudson*.groovy not found in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure jenkins job with groovy scripts, I donot know what I am doing wrong with the configuration that I could not execute even a simple groovy command like

```
println System.getenv("PATH")
```

it shows the following stack trace when the jenkins tries to build then following error is thrown

```
[workspace] $ groovy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\{Project_Name}\workspace\hudson2392295018240496017.groovy" 
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\{Project_Name}\workspace"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:780)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:360)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:367)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.perform(Groovy.java:110)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 16 more
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using default `groovy version` in jenkins configuration and have installed the jenkins plugins for groovy.

I am new to both jenkins and groovy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to have an install of Groovy which your Jenkins can see - which is the default option

Alternatively, you can add one in the global config

[image]

which can then be used in the build step

[image]

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/xxxxxx/.jenkins/jobs/gr/workspace
[workspace] $ groovy /Users/xxxxx/.jenkins/jobs/gr/workspace/hudson5419917819864291744.groovy
build
/Users/xxxxxx/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/xxxxx/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I have followed the above procedure but i am not able to build my job.It takes too long time to build.

Comment: Fyi, groovy binaries were moved from codehouse to bintray, e.g.: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/groovy/maven/groovy-binary-2.2.1.zip.