# execute groovy script in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am quite new in Jenkins and I am trying to run groovy script 'println "hello world" ' in jenkins. But i am getting below error.

```
  [Test] $ groovy /var/jenkins_home/workspace /Test/hudson481621137087598172.groovy
  FATAL: command execution failed
  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "groovy" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Test"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:249)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:218)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:935)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:454)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:465)
at hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.perform(Groovy.java:106)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1815)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 15 more
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have found some solution [Run groovy scripts in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652213/run-groovy-scripts-in-jenkins) but I am not sure how can i use that in my case.

Comment: Did you add path to your groovy binaries in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration?

Comment: No, but there is no place for do that or i don't know where can I do that.

Comment: So there is only groovy Allow token macro processing checkbox

Comment: You have been searching in Jenkins -> Configure System.

Comment: I found it (Additional groovy classpath), but what is the path of my groovy binaries??

Comment: I've added example in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add path to your groovy binaries in Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration. Once you install groovy on your machine provide path to it's installation folder. For example on my machine it's like shown on the picture below:
[image: Groovy installations]

Answer (score 0):

Before checking your Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins, you might try installing/updating your Homebrew installation and run "brew install groovy" first. This will enable you to set the groovy home path (http://macappstore.org/groovy/). Otherwise Jenkins may not save you Tool Configuration properly.

You should set GROOVY_HOME:

```
export GROOVY_HOME=/usr/local/opt/groovy/libexec
```